# Удаляем значение из JSON-массива MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

Как удалить значение в JSON-массиве MySQL?

```
options = {"cats": ["1", "10"], "tags": ["швалка", "букинг"]}
```

---

```
UPDATE `store`.`products`
SET `options` = JSON_REMOVE(`page_options` , '$.cats.10')
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`options` , '$.cats.*') = 10
```

Нужно, чтобы на выходе стало:

```
options = {"cats": ["1"], "tags": ["швалка", "букинг"]}
```

Comment: А если "cats": с одним значением, то удалялся полностью!

Comment: з.ы. ни кто не в курсе? :(

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что у вас [синтаксис JSON Path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html) неверный. В данном случае чтобы удалить второй элемента массива `cats` нужен `$[cats[1]]`. [Вам пригодится](http://jsonpath.com/). Обратите внимание что MySQL имеет свой синтаксис JSON Path и много чего не поддерживает.

Если вам нужны сложные манипуляции над данными, то стоит хранить их в нативном формате БД, а нужные вам JSON генерировать на лету.

Подходящий вам запрос вероятно мог выглядеть так (хотя на 100% не уверен что это так работает):

```
JSON_REMOVE(`page_options`, $.cats.[?(@ == 10)])
```

но как я уже говорил, MySQL не поддерживает фильтры.

Comment: Если использовать даже так, мы  всё равно не знаем какой элемент массива содержит значение 10.

Comment: 1. Найти где cats равен 10 и 2. удалить его (но как понять в какой позиции?

Comment: по мануалу: JSON_EXTRACT(`options` , '$.cats.*') = '10' правильно, но он не работает, так как выводит кучу невалидных значений.

Comment: @Roman по какому мануалу? Ваш синтаксис Path вообще неверен для MySQL (судя по документации ссылку на которую я привел выше). Правильно, не знаем и не узнаем потому что в MySQL нет функций фильтрации в JSON Path.

Comment: Пётр, я понимаю что вы имеете введу, но я не очень понимаю как это сделать с массивом JSON_CONTAINS(`page_options` , '[10]' '$.cats')

Comment: Вот здесь я смотрю: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html Мне легче если бы вы указали в частности на моём примере где я ошибся, я быстрей бы понял.

Comment: @Roman игнорируйте мои замечания об ошибках синтакса (частично), не понял что `.` и `[]` эквивалентны. Но всё равно `$.cats.10` не валидный синтакс т.к. имя не может быть цифрой, элементы массива "адресуются" только по индексу. Посмотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: Ok, сейчас посмотрим. Но хочу заметить там не цифра "cats": ["1"] не "cats": [1]. Хотя може я и ошибаюсь и для json-а нет разницы.

Comment: Извиняюсь за паузу, но НЕТ.на запрос: SELECT * FROM `cms_page` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`page_options`, '$.cats.[?(@ == '10')]')   выдаёт ошибку: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '10')]') LIMIT 0, 50' на строке 1

Comment: @Roman а я так и написал что не будет он скорее всего работать.

Comment: Так что получается что не как не возможно найти массив с ключём '10'  и удалить его? Петр, честно говоря, как то не вериться :(

Comment: @Roman ну почему же. Получаете данные, ищете, удаляете, но на клиенте. А потом обновляете на сервере. Работа c JSON в SQL сервере это приятный бонус, но никак не его основная фича, так что ничего удивительного. Я вообще удивлён что такой функционал есть, не знал о нём. Может в будущем его расширят и будет поддержка фильтров.